# Is there a numpy function for sorting according to a vector with indices?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, permutation

I want to sort a numpy vector according to another numpy vector with indices.

```py
import numpy as np
my_vector = np.array([9. 6. 21. 17. 12.])
my_indices = np.array([1. 4. 2. 0. 3.])

what_i_want = np.array([17. 9. 21. 12. 6.])
```

Is there a function for this? Something like reverse argsort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done in O(n) using advanced assignment:

```
my_vector = np.array([9., 6., 21., 17., 12.])
my_indices = np.array([1., 4., 2., 0., 3.])
my_result = np.empty_like(my_vector)
my_result[my_indices.astype(int)] = my_vector
my_result
# array([17.,  9., 21., 12.,  6.])
```

Timings on a larger example:

```
from timeit import timeit

a = np.random.random(1000000)
b = np.random.permutation(1000000).astype(float)

def fargsort():
    return(a[b.argsort()])

def fassign():
    c = np.empty_like(a)
    c[b.astype(int)] = a
    return c

np.all(fargsort() == fassign())
# True
timeit(fargsort,number=10)
# 1.2764090860000579
timeit(fassign,number=10)
# 0.17262099700747058
```

Comment: this is perfect, actually using the fact `my_indices` contains actual indices. also awesome for empiric performance comparison (and validating the results are identical)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
my_vector = np.array([9., 6., 21., 17., 12.])
my_indices = np.array([1., 4., 2., 0., 3.])

print(my_vector[my_indices.argsort()])
```

Output:

> [17.  9. 21. 12.  6.]

Comment: note: with `argsort` the elements of `my_indices` don't have to be valid indices in `my_vector`, their sorted values just have to correspond to the how you want my_vector to be sorted

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
my_vector = np.array([9., 6., 21., 17., 12.])
my_indices = np.array([1., 4., 2., 0., 3.])

res_sorted = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(my_indices,my_vector))]
print(res_sorted)
```

output:

```
[17.0, 9.0, 21.0, 12.0, 6.0]
```